# How to write to a text file in a specific format

Tags: python, streamlit

I am using Streamlit and Python to create a GUI for my project. I have a particular question about .txt files, this is the code im working on right now:

```
with open('data/test20/testing.txt', 'w+') as txt_reader:
    string = st.text_input('ENTER TEXT', value='', max_chars=None, key=None, type='default')
    txt_reader.write(string)
    st.write(string)
```

With this I am asking for an input sentence and then I am adding that sentence to my testing.txt file. The sentence should have some stuff after it so my model can analyze on it. So for example if user inputs "**Set up was easy.**", in my text file I should have "**Set up was easy.####Set=O up=O was=O easy=O .=O**" So I need to add "**####**" and every word including punctuations and add "**=O**" to every one of these items.

I am going to use `res = string.split()` to split the sentence into words and punctuations but how can I add the rest of the stuff?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `words = ['Set', 'up', 'was', 'easy', '.']; ' '.join([w + '=O' for w in words])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the problem into 2 parts: 1. Split the text to list of words and punctuations, And 2. combine them and add the `=O` after each one.

For first part, you mentioned string.split(), but please note that this method will only split the sentence on spaces, and not punctuations, so `Set up was easy.` would get you `['Set', 'up', 'was', 'easy.']` which is not what you desire. One easy way to get the result we want, is to use [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), here's an example code:

```
import re
sentence = 'Set up was easy.'
words = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", sentence)
```

The result would be that `words` list would be `['Set', 'up', 'was', 'easy', '.']`, great.

For the second part, we want to take each element of the list and conectate it with "=O", adding all elements to one big string. We can do it with this code:

```
result = sentence + "####" + " ".join([word + "=O" for word in words])
```

Finally, we can reduce the above code to:

```
import re

sentence = "Set up was easy."
sentence += "####"
result = sentence + " ".join([word + "=O" for word in re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", sentence)])
```